# I need to create a Script in Unity 3D that change the text when I click a key button (1,2,3,4), then the text change

Tags: unity-game-engine

Example: A NPC greet you, and you have multiple choises that are questions for the NPC and if you want to know one answer of this questions, you click one button (1,2,3,4). Then the text change and give you the answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have already set up your GUI and NPC Script.

Getting when a key is pressed is pretty simple in Unity: Use `UnityEngine.Input`

Example of use:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {
    //do something
}
```

This is a basic example.
`Input.GetKeyDown` returns true only when the key is pressed at that specific moment of checking (the frame). `KeyCode.Alpha1` is the key for '1' at the top of alphanumeric keyboards.
To get when the key is held down, for jumping or running, use `Input.GetKey` instead. This will be true if the key is held down at that instance, instead of only one at the beginning.
To get when the key is released, use 'Input.GetKeyUp'. This only runs once the key is let go.

For setting the color of a Textbox, use `yourTextBox.color`. I believe it works with both legacy Textboxes and TextMeshPro.

The way to do what you have is this:

1. In the Update call, check if an NPC is talking with the player.
2. If so, then check if the player has pressed 1 ,2, 3, or 4, using `Input.GetKeyDown`. (To make it nicer looking, have each option in a list and use the index of the result. KeyCode is an enum, so you can save it like any other variable.)
3. Call some function that returns the response to the answer. Return a string or something.
4. Override the text in the Textbox with the answer, and use `yourTextBox.color` to set the color as you wish.

This should cover it. I may have some typos or errors, but the basic principals should work. Also, make sure you implement it in a way that makes it easier to edit later. You don't want to write code that can't be added on later, trust me...